# I would like to show the total of a variable across months, for different subgroups

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I would like to use `ggplot2` and `dplyr` to create a chart that can show how our halls perform across months. So From Aug-Dec, I would like to see three bars for each of the three halls, and their totals.

I've got the data prepped but I can't figure how to put this using the `ggplot2` package.

```
#Events by Hall
fall2 <- fall %>% 
  group_by(Hall,Month) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(Count))

#something like this?
ggplot(Fall2, aes(Hall, Month)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = total), position = "dodge") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) + 
  ggtitle("Fall Events by Hall")
```

here's my data

```
fall2 <- structure(list(Hall = c("1959E", "1959E", "1959E", "1959E", "1959E", 
"2109 F", "2109 F", "2109 F", "2109 F", "2109 F"), Month = c("August", 
"December", "November", "October", "September", "August", "December", 
"November", "October", "September"), total = c(2, 4, 5, 11, 8, 
1, 3, 8, 7, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Hall", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:4, 5:9), group_sizes = c(5L, 5L), biggest_group_size = 5L, labels = structure(list(
    Hall = c("1959E", "2109 F")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Hall", drop = TRUE))
```

In the end I would like x-axis to show various months, and within each month it's broken up by "Hall" Ideally if this were descending by Count that would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: modified to order in descending order of Count for each month, relying on the technique here: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/ordering-categories-within-ggplot2-facets

You probably want your months in order. They're currently a character variable which will sort alphabetically. The `fct_relevel` line here makes them into an ordered factor, so that ggplot knows the order to use. (There's probably a less manual way to convert those, btw, but I don't know offhand...)

```
# library(tidyverse)  # Loads all three and a few more
library(dplyr); library(forcats); library(ggplot2)
fall2$Month <- fall2$Month %>% fct_relevel("August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
fall2 <- fall2 %>%
  ungroup() %>%    # EDIT -- source data grouped
  arrange(Month, -total) %>%
  mutate(order = row_number())

#something like this?
ggplot(fall2, aes(order, total)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = total), position = "dodge") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) + 
  ggtitle("Fall Events by Hall") +
  facet_wrap(~Month, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = fall2$order, labels = fall2$Hall,expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: You missed one last request by OP: `Ideally if this were descending by Count that would be best.`

Comment: @JonSpring Yes! This is great, however My code does not dogdge, it only stacks the results, yet I copied your code exactly. This is when I include the larger dataset with about 19 Halls

Comment: @JonSpring instead of a bar for each hall in each facet, it is 1 bar with a bunch of overlapping names with each bar on the stack.

Comment: @JonSpring Ran the code you provided with the subset of data I provided and it does not work dodged :/

Comment: Did the source data change in the OP? It is now grouped. I have changed by suggestion for the ordering step to first `ungroup` the data, which makes the dodging work, since it needs to establish the order across all rows, not just within groups.

Comment: @JonSpring Didn't change, but it works now!!! I have about 19 additional halls in the larger dataframe, I can probably look this up but do you know how to put the hall labels at an angle so they don't get all smudged together?

Comment: Glad it works now. I guess I mixed something up on my end. To adjust axis labels add `+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))` or whatever angle you want.